all-the-icons-dired does not load in emacsclient
I am using all-the-icons-dired with
(use-package all-the-icons
  :if (display-graphic-p)
  :config
  (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'all-the-icons-dired-mode))

If I start emacs, the icons load. But if start using emacsclient -c ., it does not load at all.
Ubuntu - 22.04
emacs - 27.1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon # systemd service entry


You're running Emacs as a daemon, so your problem will be that you are testing (display-graphic-p) when Emacs starts:
display-graphic-p is a byte-compiled Lisp function in `frame.el'.

(display-graphic-p &optional DISPLAY)

Return non-nil if DISPLAY is a graphic display.
Graphical displays are those which are capable of displaying several
frames and several different fonts at once.  This is true for displays
that use a window system such as X, and false for text-only terminals.
DISPLAY can be a display name, a frame, or nil (meaning the selected
frame's display).

You're not passing the (optional) DISPLAY argument, and therefore it is nil, meaning the return value will be based on the selected frame at that time.
When a daemon starts, there is no graphical display (there are no graphical frames); so anything that requires one at start-up time will fail.
You can use server-after-make-frame-hook or after-make-frame-functions to act when a frame is created, at which point (if it's a graphical frame) you would get a different result from that predicate.

In your case, I suggest that you instead make your dired-mode-hook function be one that checks display-graphic-p and only calls all-the-icons-dired-mode if that test passes.
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'my-dired-mode-hook)

(defun my-dired-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `dired-mode' config called via `dired-mode-hook'."
  (when (display-graphic-p)
    (all-the-icons-dired-mode 1)))

However it turns out all-the-icons-dired-mode tests display-graphic-p itself, and so you can in fact safely use:
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook #'all-the-icons-dired-mode)

Which is what you had in the first place, except it was all wrapped up in some use-package code with the problematic conditional test.  I don't know much about use-package, but I imagine that you can simply delete :if (display-graphic-p) from that code in order to get the desired result.

Can you tell me how to make dired-mode-hook to do the check. I am completely new to elisp. I tried (add-hook 'dired-mode-hook (if (display-graphic-p) 'all-the-icons-dired-mode))). But it is adding nil on the daemon dired. I guess I can not modify dired-mode-hook myself.

I've added an example (and then a simplification, after I checked out the package in question).  Note that when you add to a hook variable, you must add a function.
